# Building Bayesian Models with insignificant independent variables

Tags: regression, bayesian

My main goal is to use four independent variables (y~x1,x2,x3,x4) and develop a Bayes Linear Regression model. However when I ran a simple linear regression model using these same four independent variables I found out that none of these independent variables are significant.

Does this matter at all that these independent variables were insignificant in predicting y to begin with, when I build a Bayes Linear model?

Comment: It depends on what, and how strong, your prior information is.  A weak or uninformative prior will tend to replicate the classical frequentist analysis.  But if your question is "is it valid to use a Bayesian model if a null frequentist model cannot be rejected?" then the answer is yes.  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @AndrewM that is perfect, I did feel the same way..."Using Bayesian model because Freqentist model is insignificant in the first place"